# How to save a read-only file as a different file extension in an excel macro?

Tags: vba, excel-2007, excel-2010, file-extension

I have a macro setup to automatically open/save a file that I am opening from the web. The web format is a #csv.gz format. I have code that currently just saves the file in the default location (which I have changed to c:\files). I want to write a macro that will keep the filename of the file, but change the extention to just file.xlsm. Is there a way to do this with VBA/excel? The reason while I need to change the extension is because it currently does not work with my formulas. The default save code I have just saves the file as a #csv.txt.

Is this possible?

Comment: see `Workbook.SaveAs` and then lookat `FileFormat` argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrate this code into your own:

```
Sub SaveIt()

Dim wkb As Workbook

Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook 'change to your workbook reference

wkb.SaveAs Replace(wkb.Name, ".txt", ""), 52 'change ".txt" to ".csv" if need be

End Sub
```

See [Excel File Type Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241279%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information the 52.

Comment: Using your code, I was able to rearrange mine and ended using the following:
    `code`Dim wkb As Workbook

Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook 'change to your workbook reference

wkb.SaveAs Replace(wkb.Name, "#csv.gz", ""), 52 'change "csv.gz" to ".xlsm" if need be